# Do all C++ enums have at least two legal values?

Tags: c++, enums, language-lawyer

While working with some custom comparators, I encountered the need for a type that only had a single possible value.  There are types like `std::nullptr_t` and empty structs where this is the case.

Then I considered the possibility of using an enum. I might declare an enum with a single value, something like

```
enum E
{
  only_value // BUT IS IT??
};
```

But it seems that the standard says that all of the underlying type's values, which fit into the "smallest bitfield" that can contain the declared values, are valid.

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum):

> (The source value, as converted to the enumeration's underlying type if floating-point, is in range if it would fit in the smallest bit field large enough to hold all enumerators of the target enumeration.)

If you declare an enum with only a single enumerator, the smallest it can be is one bit.  Following that logic, the unnamed enumerator with the bit's other value should be legal.   If an enum is based on a signed integer, then `-1` and `0` are always legal. On an unsigned integer, `0` and `1` are always legal.

Is there something else in the standard that makes the unnamed bit value illegal or UB?

Comment: I am not a language lawyer, but for me, to store an enum with a single value, you need **0** bits, not 1 (provided the value is 0).

Comment: @prapin Maybe...but nullptr takes up space, so I guess an enum always would too. I wonder if there's a loophole open to allow it to be optimized away.

Comment: @prapin Think of it this way: `enum ultimate { answer=42 };` always takes **7** bits, and all the values from -64 to 63 are legal.

Comment: @Spencer, how does `enum ultimate { answer = 42};` take up 7 bits?  In binary, the number 42 is represented as 101010, which is 6 bits.  On 8 bit machines, it would take up 8 bits because 8 bits is the minimum addressable size.  I'm confused.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Because the underlying type is signed. 6 bits to fit the `42` plus a sign bit. A "bit field" can be smaller than 8 bits.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that `enum E { value = 0; }` only has one value, that of 0. The standard has this to say:

> **[dcl.enum]/8** ... Otherwise [if the underlying type is not fixed - IT], for an enumeration where *e<sub>min</sub>* is the smallest enumerator and *e<sub>max</sub>* is the largest, the values of the enumeration are the values in the range *b<sub>min</sub>* to *b<sub>max</sub>*, defined as follows: Let *K* be 1 for a two's complement representation and 0 for a ones' complement or sign-magnitude representation. *b<sub>max</sub>* is the smallest value greater than or equal to *max(|e<sub>min</sub>| − K, |e<sub>maxn</sub>|)* and equal to *2<sup>M</sup> − 1*, where *M* is a non-negative integer. *b<sub>min</sub>* is zero if *e<sub>min</sub>* is non-negative and *−(b<sub>max</sub> + K)* otherwise.

When *e<sub>min</sub> == e<sub>max</sub> == 0*, this math also produces *b<sub>min</sub> == b<sub>max</sub> == 0*, by my count.

However, before you get your hopes up, see Footnote 96:

> 96. This set of values is used to define promotion and conversion semantics for the enumeration type. It does not preclude an expression of enumeration type from having a value that falls outside this range.

I must admit it's not immediately obvious to me how to produce an expression of enumeration type with value outside the range. At least, `static_cast` to enumeration type exhibits undefined behavior if the value being cast falls outside the range.

Comment: So, is cpprereference's assertion that the bitfield size defines the range incorrect?

Comment: @Spencer the answer is about pre-two's complement only C++ (C++17 and below). C++20+ is worded in terms of integer width https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.enum#8.sentence-2

Comment: Igor, please see @LanguageLawyer's comment.  This answer won't be complete until you address its C++ version specificity.

Answer (score 1):

@Igor's answer is correct as far as older (C++17 and older) versions of C++ go.
I was perplexed that the standard language he presented didn't match what cppreference showed, until @LanguageLawyer pointed out in a comment that Igor was working off an old version of the Standard.

In C++20 and later, the language is different (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.enum#8.sentence-2).

Interestingly,

> For an enumeration whose underlying type is fixed, the values of the enumeration are the values of the underlying type.

Meaning, if an enumeration has its type specified, *the full range of values for the underlying type are allowed for that enumeration!*   This makes it impossible to have an enum based on an unsigned type that "just fits".

But more pertinent to my question is what follows:

> Otherwise, the values of the enumeration are the values representable by a hypothetical integer type with minimal width M such that all enumerators can be represented. The width of the smallest bit-field large enough to hold all the values of the enumeration type is M. It is possible to define an enumeration that has values not defined by any of its enumerators.

So, given

```
enum E
{
  dummy = 0
};
```

the smallest bit-field is 1 bit, and it *must have* two values, the other one being `-1` (since the default underlying type in C++ is `int`).

The sentence that follows in the Standard

> If the enumerator-list is empty, the values of the enumeration are as if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0.

might seem worrying at first, until we realize the Standard makes a distinction between "enumerators" (the names inside the enum declaration) and "values".  All it means is that

```
enum E0 { };
```

has an implicit enumerator, e.g. the same as if declared

```
enum E0 { dummy = 0 };
```

and it also has 1 bit to work with and the allowed `-1` value.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Does this look right?